# Visualforce Error : The dependent picklist 'Class' requires its controlling field 'Brand' to be present on the page

Tags: apex, visualforce, dependent-picklist

While I'm trying to get the dependent picklist as input filed in vf page I'm getting the below error.

---

***Visualforce Error The dependent picklist 'Class' requires its controlling field 'Brand' to be present on the page.***

---

VF Page code:

```
 <apex:inputField value="{!vehicle.Class__c}"/>
```

In My Vehicle__c object there are three fields.

```
Brand-parent
class-(dependent on Brand)
model-(dependent on class)
```

How can I display these fileds on my vf page.

Answer (score 2):

As per the documentation

> Pages must include the controlling field for a dependent picklist. Failing to include the controlling field on the page causes a runtime error when the page displays.

In your case, `Class__c` is a dependent picklist and it's controlling field is `Brand__c`. This means values of `Class__c` are populated when you select any picklist value from it's parent. And since you haven't included controlling picklist field `Brand__c`, you're getting an error.

So you must include controlling field in the Visualforce Page. So it should be something like this:

```
 <apex:inputField value="{!vehicle.Brand__c}"/>
 <apex:inputField value="{!vehicle.Class__c}"/>
```

Comment: The above thing is working, but it was displaying as text fields. But they are picklist fields in object.

Comment: @Lokesh You might have used `inputText`. Documentation clearly says that, page will give you runtime error. Try adding it's controlling field.