# Visualforce Error The dependent picklist requires its controlling field on the page

Tags: visualforce, dependent-picklist

hope you are having a good day!

I could find two links related my questions.

[Visualforce Error : The dependent picklist 'Class' requires its controlling field 'Brand' to be present on the page](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/167455/visualforce-error-the-dependent-picklist-class-requires-its-controlling-fiel)

[Visualforce Error - The dependent picklist requires its controlling field on the page](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/248595/visualforce-error-the-dependent-picklist-requires-its-controlling-field-on-the)

According to the two links above, I think I should paste this.

```
<apex:inputField value="{!Grant__c.Global_Regions__c}"/>
<apex:inputField value="{!Grant__c.Geographic_Focus__c}"/>
```

I have no coding background so don't know how to solve this problem for now.

Can you advise me where should I add the code?

My Org have a Project object with custom VF button.

We add Grant Object record by using that button.

Grant Object have Global region - Geographic focus fields(Country - State)

I create 'Field dependencies' on them then.

I face the error message when I use the VF button.

I paste the VF code below, please advise me.

```
<apex:page standardController="Project__c" extensions="SearchGrantsController" docType="html-5.0" title="Search Grants for {!Project__c.Name}" sidebar="false" >

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{!URLFOR($Resource.TableSorterJS,'/jquery.tablesorter.js')}"></script>
    <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.TableSorterJS,'/themes/blue/style.css')}"/>
    <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.TableSorterJS,'/themes/blue/asc.gif')}"/>
    <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.TableSorterJS,'/themes/blue/desc.gif')}"/>
    <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.TableSorterJS,'/themes/blue/bg.gif')}"/>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function (){
            //see if the page is lightning or classic
            if(document.referrer.indexOf(".lightning.force.com") > 0){
                console.log('lightning page');
                var e = document.getElementsByClassName('classicStyle');
                for(var i = 0; i < e.length; i++){
                    e[i].classList.add('hide');
                };
                
                console.log('hid classic version');
            }else{
                console.log('classic page');
                var e = document.getElementsByClassName('lightningStyle');
                for(var i = 0; i < e.length; i++){
                    e[i].classList.add('hide');
                };
                console.log('hid lighting version');
            }
        };

        var simpleSearch, advancedSearch, advProp, isLightning;

        $(document).ready(function(){
            sLink = $('[id$="searchLink"]');
        sLink2 = $('#searchLink2');
            advancedSearch = $('[id$="advancedCriteriaTable"]');
        advancedSearch2 = $('[id$="advancedCriteriaTable2"]');
            $('[id$="resultTable"]').tablesorter({headers:{0:{sorter:false}}});
            $('select.multipicklist').each(function(){
                console.log('MPL!');
                $(this).attr('size','6');
            });

            $('.datepicker').datepicker({
                format: 'yyyy-MM-dd'            
            });
            $('input[type=date]').on('change',function(){
                $('.datepicker').hide();
            })
            
        })

        function toggleSearch(){
            //simpleSearch.toggle();
            var innerLink = sLink.html();
            if(innerLink == 'Show Advanced Options'){
                sLink.html('Hide Advanced Options');
            }
            else{
                sLink.html('Show Advanced Options');
            }
            $('[id$="simpleBtn"]').toggle();
            advancedSearch.toggle();
        }

      function toggleProjectSearch(){
        //simpleSearch.toggle();
        var innerLink = sLink2.html();
        if(innerLink == 'Show Advanced Options'){
          sLink2.html('Hide Advanced Options');
        }
        else{
          sLink2.html('Show Advanced Options');
        }
        $('[id$="simpleBtn2"]').toggle();
        advancedSearch2.toggle();
      }

        function addToProject(id){
            
            var chxbx = $('[id$="'+id+'_chxbx"]').find("input[type='checkbox']")
            console.log(chxbx);
            chxbx.prop('checked',true);
        }
        function toggleTabs(str){
            if(str=='grant'){
                $('[id$="grantSearch"]').attr('style','display:block;');
                $('[id$="projectSearch"]').attr('style','display:none;');
                $('[id$="gtab"]').addClass('active');$('[id$="gtab"]').removeClass('inactive');
                $('[id$="ptab"]').addClass('inactive');$('[id$="ptab"]').removeClass('active');
            }
            else{
                $('[id$="grantSearch"]').attr('style','display:none;');
                $('[id$="projectSearch"]').attr('style','display:block;');
                $('[id$="gtab"]').addClass('inactive');$('[id$="gtab"]').removeClass('active');
                $('[id$="ptab"]').addClass('active');$('[id$="ptab"]').removeClass('inactive');
            }
        }

        function selectAll(el){
            if($(el).prop('checked')){
                $('[id$="resultTable"]').find('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(){
                    $(this).prop('checked',true);
                });
            }
            else{

                $('[id$="resultTable"]').find('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(){
                    $(this).prop('checked',false);
                });
            }
        }

    </script>

    <style type="text/css">
    .myBtn {
        border-radius: 5px !important;
        color: #fff !important;
        background: #337ab7 !important;
        border-color: #2e6da4 !important;
        padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px !important;
    }
    #searchBox{
        width: 80%;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
        background-color: lightgrey;
    }

    .centerBox {
        position: relative;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    #resultTable > thead > tr > th {
        text-align: center;
    }

    .panel {
        width: 90%;
    }

    #advancedCriteriaTable, #simpleCriteriaTable {
        margin-bottom: -10px;
    }
    #advancedCriteriaTable .form-control{
        font-size: 8px !important;
    }

    .btnDisabled {
        background: grey !important;
    }

    .disabledLink {
        pointer-events: none;
        cursor: default;
        color: grey;
    }

    .multipicklist {
        font-size: 8px !important;
        border-radius: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075);
        padding: 6px 12px;
    }

    
    .inactive {
        border-top-right-radius: 5px;
        border-top-left-radius: 5px;
        background-color: #337ab7 !important;
        border: 1px solid lightgrey;
    }

    .inactive > a{
        color: white !important;
    }

    .nav-tabs > li > a:hover {
        border-top-radius: 5px;
        background-color: lightgrey !important;
        color: #337ab7 !important;
    }
        
    .hide {
        display:none; 
        }

    </style>
    
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <br/>
        <div class="text-center"><h2 >{!Project__c.Name}</h2></div>
        <br/>
        <apex:pageMessages escape="false"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{!Project__c.State__c}" rendered="false"/>
        <apex:outputField value="{!Project__c.Sector__c}" rendered="false"/>
        
        <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!Project__c.Id != null}">
            <apex:form style="width:50%;position:relative;margin:0 auto">
                <div align="center" style="margin-bottom:10px">
                    <apex:commandButton action="{!URLFOR($Action.Project__c.View,Project__c.Id)}" value="Return to Project" styleClass="myBtn"/>
                </div>
            </apex:form>
            <div class="panel panel-primary centerBox" id="searchBox">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                        <li role="presentation" class="active" id="gtab"><a href="javascript:toggleTabs('grant');">Search by Grant</a></li>
                        <li role="presentation" class="inactive" id="ptab"><a href="javascript:toggleTabs('project');">Search By Project</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <apex:form style="font-size:11px !important;">
                        

                        <div id="grantSearch" style="display:block;">
                            <!-- Simple Search by Name Only -->
                            <table class="table" id="simpleCriteriaTable">
                                <thead></thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="2">
                                            <apex:input type="text" styleClass="form-control" html-placeholder="Search For Grants" value="{!searchName}"/>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>

                                </tbody>
                                <tfoot>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="2">
                                            <apex:commandButton id="simpleBtn" action="{!doSimpleSearch}" styleClass="myBtn" value="Search"/>
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="text-align:right">
                                            <a id="searchLink" href="javascript:toggleSearch();">Show Advanced Options</a> 
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tfoot>
                            </table>

                            <!-- Advanced Search -->
                            <table class="table" id="advancedCriteriaTable" style="display:none;">
                                <thead></thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td width="50%">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label class="checkbox inline">Eligibility</label>
                                                <apex:inputField styleClass="multipicklist" id="eligibility_crit" value="{!dummyGrant.Eligibility__c}"/>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td width="50%">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label class="checkbox inline" for="geofocus_crit">Geographic Focus</label>
                                                <apex:inputField styleClass="multipicklist" id="geofocus_crit" value="{!dummyGrant.Geographic_Focus__c}"/>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td width="50%">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <center><label for="itclass_crit">IT Classification</label></center>
                                                <apex:inputField styleClass="form-control" id="itclass_crit" value="{!dummyGrant.IT_Classification__c}"/>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>

                                        <td width="50%">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <center><label for="funder_crit">Funder Type</label></center>
                                                <apex:inputField styleClass="form-control" id="funder_crit" value="{!dummyGrant.Funder_Type__c}"/>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td >
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <center><label for="deadline_crit">Deadline Date Range</label></center>
                                                <div class="form-group" id="deadline_crit" >
                                                    <p>Start:&nbsp;</p>
                                                    <div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd">
                                                        <apex:input styleclass="form-control" type="date" id="deadline_crit1" value="{!deadlineStart}"/>
                                                        <div class="input-group-addon">
                                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    
                                                    <span style="min-width:30px;"><p>End:&nbsp;</p></span>
                                                    <div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd">
                                                        <apex:input styleclass="form-control" type="date" id="deadline_crit2" value="{!deadlineEnd}"/>
                                                        <div class="input-group-addon">
                                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                    
                                        <td >
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <center><label for="expir_crit">Expiration Date Range</label></center>
                                                <div class="form-group" id="expir_crit" >
                                                    <span style="min-width:30px;"><p>Start:&nbsp;</p></span>
                                                    <div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd">
                                                        <apex:input styleclass="form-control" type="date" id="expir_crit1" value="{!expirationStart}"/>
                                                        <div class="input-group-addon">
                                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    
                                                    <span style="min-width:30px;"><p>End:&nbsp;</p></span>
                                                    <div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd">
                                                        <apex:input styleclass="form-control" type="date" id="expir_crit2" value="{!expirationEnd}"/>
                                                        <div class="input-group-addon">
                                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                            

                                    
                                </tbody>
                                <tfoot>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td >
                                            <apex:commandButton id="advBtn" action="{!doAdvancedSearch}" styleClass="myBtn" value="Search"/>
                                        </td>
                                        <!-- <td style="text-align:right">
                                            <a href="javascript:toggleSearch();">Simple Search</a> 
                                        </td> -->
                                    </tr>
                                </tfoot>
                            </table> 
                        </div>

                        <div id="projectSearch" style="display:none;">
                            <table class="table">
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td >
                                            <!-- <h3>Get Grants From Existing Project</h3></center> -->
                                            <div class="form-group" style="width:50%">
                                                <!-- <label for="projName">Project Name</label> -->
                                                <c:AutoComplete ComponentLabel="Project Name" for="projName" SObject="Project__c" 
                                                Label="Name" Value="Id" ReturnValue="{!searchProjId}" Details="Autocomplete_Detail_Display__c">
                                                    <apex:input id="projName" styleClass="form-control"/>
                                                </c:AutoComplete>
                                                <small class="text-muted">Search for Project-related Grants</small>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>           
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                                <tfoot>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <apex:commandButton action="{!doACSearch}" id="simpleBtn2" styleClass="myBtn" value="Search"/>
                                        </td>
                      <td style="text-align:right">
                        <a id="searchLink2" href="javascript:toggleProjectSearch();">Show Advanced Options</a>
                      </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tfoot>
                            </table>

                <table class="table" id="advancedCriteriaTable2" style="display:none;">
                  <thead></thead>
                  <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td width="50%">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="checkbox inline">Eligibility</label>
                        <apex:inputField styleClass="multipicklist" id="eligibility_crit2" value="{!dummyGrant2.Eligibility__c}"/>
                      </div>
                    </td>
                    <td width="50%">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="checkbox inline" for="geofocus_crit">Geographic Focus</label>
                        <apex:inputField styleClass="multipicklist" id="geofocus_crit2" value="{!dummyGrant2.Geographic_Focus__c}"/>
                      </div>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td width="50%">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <center><label for="itclass_crit">IT Classification</label></center>
                        <apex:inputField styleClass="form-control" id="itclass_crit2" value="{!dummyGrant2.IT_Classification__c}"/>
                      </div>
                    </td>

                    <td width="50%">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <center><label for="funder_crit">Funder Type</label></center>
                        <apex:inputField styleClass="form-control" id="funder_crit2" value="{!dummyGrant2.Funder_Type__c}"/>
                      </div>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td >
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <center><label for="deadline_crit">Deadline Date Range</label></center>
                        <div class="form-group" id="deadline_crit0" >
                          <p>Start:&nbsp;</p>
                          <div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd">
                            <apex:input styleclass="form-control" type="date" id="deadline_crit3" value="{!deadlineStart2}"/>
                            <div class="input-group-addon">
                              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
                            </div>
                          </div>

                          <span style="min-width:30px;"><p>End:&nbsp;</p></span>
                          <div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd">
                            <apex:input styleclass="form-control" type="date" id="deadline_crit4" value="{!deadlineEnd2}"/>
                            <div class="input-group-addon">
                              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </td>

                    <td >
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <center><label for="expir_crit">Expiration Date Range</label></center>
                        <div class="form-group" id="expir_crit0" >
                          <span style="min-width:30px;"><p>Start:&nbsp;</p></span>
                          <div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd">
                            <apex:input styleclass="form-control" type="date" id="expir_crit3" value="{!expirationStart2}"/>
                            <div class="input-group-addon">
                              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
                            </div>
                          </div>

                          <span style="min-width:30px;"><p>End:&nbsp;</p></span>
                          <div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd">
                            <apex:input styleclass="form-control" type="date" id="expir_crit4" value="{!expirationEnd2}"/>
                            <div class="input-group-addon">
                              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
                            </div>
                          </div>

                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </td>
                  </tr>



                  </tbody>
                  <tfoot>
                  <tr>
                    <td >
                      <apex:commandButton id="advBtn2" action="{!doAdvancedACSearch}" styleClass="myBtn" value="Search"/>
                    </td>
                    <!-- <td style="text-align:right">
                      <a href="javascript:toggleSearch();">Simple Search</a>
                    </td> -->
                  </tr>
                  </tfoot>
                </table>
                            </div>

                    </apex:form>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- RESULTS PANEL -->
            <div class="panel panel-default centerBox">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <apex:form >

                        <table class="table table-bordered tablesorter" id="resultTable">
                            <caption>
                                Showing page {!currentPageNumber} of {!pageSize}<br/>
                                <apex:commandLink action="{!first}" styleclass="{!IF(hasPrevious,'','disabledLink')}">First</apex:commandLink>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                <apex:commandLink action="{!previous}" styleclass="{!IF(hasPrevious,'','disabledLink')}">Previous</apex:commandLink>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                <apex:commandLink action="{!next}" styleclass="{!IF(hasNext,'','disabledLink')}">Next</apex:commandLink>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                <apex:commandLink action="{!last}" styleclass="{!IF(hasNext,'','disabledLink')}">Last</apex:commandLink>
                                
                            </caption>
                            <thead>
                                <tr style="background:white !important">
                                    <td colspan="7">
                                        <apex:commandButton disabled="{!searchResults.size = 0}" action="{!save}" styleClass="myBtn" value="Add to Project"/>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class="row">
                                    <th class="col-md-1">Select&nbsp;<input type="checkbox" onchange="selectAll(this);"/></th>
                                    <th class="col-md-2">Name</th>
                                    <th class="col-md-6">Summary</th>
                                    <th class="col-md-1">Authority</th>
                                    <th class="col-md-1">Deadline</th>
                                    <th class="col-md-1">Score</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>

                            <tbody>
                                <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!searchResults.size > 0}">
                                    
                                        
                                    
                                    <apex:repeat value="{!searchResults}" var="result">
                                        <tr class="row">
                                            
                                            <td class="col-md-1" style="text-align:center;" id="{!result.grant.Id}_chxbx"><apex:inputcheckbox value="{!result.checked}"/></td>
                                            <!-- Name column has Hover. controlled by Grant__c Mini Page Layout -->
                                            <td class="col-md-2 classicStyle">
                                                <a href="{!URLFOR($Action.Grant__c.View,result.grant.Id)}" target="_blank" class="nameHover" id="{!result.grant.Id}" 
                                                onmouseover="LookupHoverDetail.getHover('{!result.grant.Id}', '/{!result.grant.Id}/m?retURL=%2F{!result.grant.Id}&isAjaxRequest=1').show();"
                                                onmouseout="LookupHoverDetail.getHover('{!result.grant.Id}', '/{!result.grant.Id}/m?retURL=%2F{!result.grant.Id}&isAjaxRequest=1').hide();" 
                                                >
                                                {!result.grant.Name}</a>
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="col-md-2 lightningStyle">
                                                <a href="{!URLFOR($Action.Grant__c.View,result.grant.Id)}" target="_blank" id="{!result.grant.Id}">
                                                {!result.grant.Name}
                                                </a>
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="col-md-6">{!result.summary}</td>
                                            <td class="col-md-1">{!result.grant.Authority__r.Name}</td>
                                            <td class="col-md-1">
                                                <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!result.nextdeadline != null}">
                                                    <apex:outputText value="{0,date,MM/dd/yyyy}">
                                                        <apex:param value="{!result.nextdeadline}"/>
                                                    </apex:outputText>
                                                </apex:outputPanel>
                                                <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!result.nextdeadline = null}">
                                                    No deadline
                                                </apex:outputPanel>
                                            </td>
                                            <td class="col-md-1">
                                           
                                                {!result.sortPercent}
                                            <span>%</span>
                                                
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </apex:repeat>
                                </apex:outputPanel>
                                <!-- If no records found -->
                                <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!searchResults.size = 0}">
                                    <tr class="row">
                                        <td colspan="5" style="text-align:center;">No records found!</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </apex:outputPanel>
                            </tbody>
                            <tfoot>
                                <tr style="background:white !important">
                                    <td colspan="7">
                                        Showing page {!currentPageNumber} of {!pageSize}<br/>
                                        <apex:commandLink action="{!first}" styleclass="{!IF(hasPrevious,'','disabledLink')}">First</apex:commandLink>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                        <apex:commandLink action="{!previous}" styleclass="{!IF(hasPrevious,'','disabledLink')}">Previous</apex:commandLink>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                        <apex:commandLink action="{!next}" styleclass="{!IF(hasNext,'','disabledLink')}">Next</apex:commandLink>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                        <apex:commandLink action="{!last}" styleclass="{!IF(hasNext,'','disabledLink')}">Last</apex:commandLink>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr style="background:white !important">
                                    <td colspan="7">
                                        <apex:commandButton disabled="{!searchResults.size = 0}" action="{!save}" styleClass="myBtn" value="Add to Project"/>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tfoot>
                        </table>
                    </apex:form>
                </div>
            </div>
                
        </apex:outputPanel>
    </div>

</apex:page>
```

Comment: You don't need to put [Answered] in your title. Just accept the answer (which you've already done, thank you) to indicate to the community that the question is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are displaying a table where one row is defined as:

```
<tr>
    <td width="50%">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="checkbox inline">Eligibility</label>
            <apex:inputField styleClass="multipicklist" id="eligibility_crit" value="{!dummyGrant.Eligibility__c}"/>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td width="50%">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="checkbox inline" for="geofocus_crit">Geographic Focus</label>
            <apex:inputField styleClass="multipicklist" id="geofocus_crit" value="{!dummyGrant.Geographic_Focus__c}"/>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Your second column (the `<td>` has the dependent picklist.  While the matter of how you layout your page is up to you and business requirements, the following would certainly work as a place to get started (add a new column)

```
<tr>
    <td width="33%">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="checkbox inline">Eligibility</label>
            <apex:inputField styleClass="multipicklist" id="eligibility_crit" value="{!dummyGrant.Eligibility__c}"/>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td width="33%">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="checkbox inline">Global Region</label>
            <apex:inputField styleClass="picklist" id="globalRegion" value="{!dummyGrant.Global_Regions__c}"/>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td width="33%">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="checkbox inline" for="geofocus_crit">Geographic Focus</label>
            <apex:inputField styleClass="multipicklist" id="geofocus_crit" value="{!dummyGrant.Geographic_Focus__c}"/>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

and then repeat for the second table `advancedCriteriaTable2`.

Table styling questions are best researched on stackoverflow

Comment: Thank you for this! I have added and tried to save on my Sandbox. But I have error message - Error: SearchGrants line 570, column 140: The element type "apex:commandlink" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</apex:commandlink>" , Error: The element type "apex:commandlink" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</apex:commandlink>".

Comment: This is working! I forgot to add '2' on <id="globalRegion"> and <value="{!dummyGrant.Global_Regions__c}">, after add '2' each of them it is working. Thank you so much. By the way why is the id name form look like this? <id="geofocus_crit"> I kust wonder why put '_crit' and the meaning. Because the Global Region field we added does not follow that format. Thank you so much for this.

Comment: id attributes can be anything; perhaps it meant "geofocus criteria". You'd have to ask the prior developer. 

As a service to the Community, if the answer addressed your needs; consider denoting it as "answered"

Comment: Thank you so much, happy to have dependency filed and could learn new thing :)